# mass replace of values in more tables by a highest value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with OWN_ID and OWN_Email -

```
own_id      |   own_email
-----------------------------------------------
3ace7cf80edd    |   email@example.com
3acf6af33ff7    |   email@example.com
3acda2524e00    |   email@example.com
3ad75583c9a7    |   spam@example.com
3ad74b018999    |   spam@example.com
```

etc.

the problem is that it should contain only a single ID per Email, also I need to replace all OWN_ID values in another table by highest OWN_ID value of the OWN_Email

sql create:

```
CREATE TABLE  `blahblah.`eventowner` (
  `OWN_ID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `OWN_Email` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnDateFormat` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnWeekStart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnDayStart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnDayEnd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OWN_ID`),
  KEY `OwnerEmailIndex` (`OWN_Email`),
  KEY `OwnerIndex` (`OWN_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci

CREATE TABLE  `blahblah`.`event` (
  `EVN_ID` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVNGRP_ID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVNOWN_ID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVNRCR_ID` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Evn_EditCounter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Evn_Created` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Evn_Modified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnFolder` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnTitle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnNote` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
  `EvnLocation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnPriority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnComplete` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnColor` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnClass` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnShareType` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnTimeFormat` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnType` varchar(127) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnStatus` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnOrganizer` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnContact` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnURL` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnStartDate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnStartTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnEndDate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnEndTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnRID` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnUID` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnExpire` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnSequence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EvnFlags` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `EventGroupClassIndex` (`EVNGRP_ID`,`EvnClass`),
  KEY `EventGroupFolderIndex` (`EVN_ID`,`EVNGRP_ID`,`EvnFolder`),
  KEY `EventRIDIndex` (`EvnRID`),
  KEY `EventUIDIndex` (`EvnUID`),
  KEY `EventGroupRCRIndex` (`EVN_ID`,`EVNGRP_ID`,`EVNRCR_ID`),
  KEY `EventExpireIndex` (`EvnExpire`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci
```

Comment: Just making sure I get this right: You want to remove email duplicates, keeping the highest-valued entries, and then replace all references to the deleted duplicates to the new unique, highest-valued IDs. Right?

Comment: that is exactly what I want to do, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Is there a foreign key constraint on the table?  Could you post the CREATE TABLE statements for all the tables involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete t1 from table t1, table t2
where t1.own_email= t2.own_email
and t1.own_id < t2.own_id

update othertable, table
set othertable.own_id= table.own_id
where othertable.own_email= table.own_email;

Answer (score 1):

Could accomplish this fairly simple using a transaction that nukes the whole table.

```
BEGIN;
 SELECT own_email, max(own_Id) INTO temptable FROM table GROUP BY own_email
 TRUNCATE table;
 INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM temptable;
 DELETE temptable;
COMMIT;
```

But, that Isn't the best way -- you can also do it by deleting just the right rows.

```
DELETE FROM table AS d WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT own_id FROM table AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT max(own_id) FROM table AS i
    GROUP BY own_email
    WHERE t.own_email = i.own_email
  )
  AND d.own_id = t.own_id
  AND d.own_email = t.own_email
);
```

Here we delete all `own_id`s, that aren't the `max(own_id)` for an E-mail.

This can be accomplished with `NOT IN` (understanding the caveat on nulls), or an anti-join on the table being deleted from